# How to load an external file from within an HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have static HTML files, each looks like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    p {
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <p>dul tank ksk sk skek kejk jk sk sksjk sdsfkdsfs ai nvnei kdsfue v sjksfspas ksdsjkfs fsakd;afksajf;akd fa</p>
        <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
        <p>dul tank ksk sk skek kejk jk sk sksjk sdsfkdsfs ai nvnei kdsfue v sjksfspas ksdsjkfs fsakd;afksajf;akd fa</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Because

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    p {
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });
    </script>
```

is the common code, I want to extract it and put into a new file named `common.html`.

## Question

I try load `common.html` with `link` tag but it produces a strange output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="import" href="common.html"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <p>dul tank ksk sk skek kejk jk sk sksjk sdsfkdsfs ai nvnei kdsfue v sjksfspas ksdsjkfs fsakd;afksajf;akd fa</p>
        <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
        <p>dul tank ksk sk skek kejk jk sk sksjk sdsfkdsfs ai nvnei kdsfue v sjksfspas ksdsjkfs fsakd;afksajf;akd fa</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the proper way to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include HTML code just by linking it that way.

If you want to have a templating engine managing your website either go for a flat website generator like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), use a framework such as Ruby on Rails or [Symfony](https://symfony.com) or roll out your own (using php, for instance).

Comment: I have to use static HTML files.

Comment: Then Jekyll is a good way to go. Check their templating feature [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).

Comment: Hey, @SingleFighter, any luck with this? Did you settle for a specific technology in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jekyll.  It is a static webpage generator.  https://jekyllrb.com/